# Can we use Appium and Selenium together for testing and comparing app data with web data?

Tags: selenium, testing, appium

We are testing on moblie app using Appium, Which feature is to upload a video on Server. After uploading video it will be visible on Dashboard of Website. The dashboard feature is not present in mobile app. So here We need to check that Video related details using Selenium as it is on Website. Any Suggestion? How can we do this without performing separate tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is integration testing so are in effect two different tests/steps.

You could do it in one project though so you could do something like:

1. open your mobile app using Appium
2. upload the video
3. open a browser using webdriver
4. navigate to the relevant page and check the video uploaded
5. close the browser
6. continue testing or close the mobile app